# What is the expression on RegularExpressionValidator to check if the Textbox text is 6 or more characters long?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

what is the format for the RegularExpressionValidator control to check if the textbox to be validated has 6 or more characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^.{6,}$` will do it in most variants of regex. Let me verify it works in this specific case.

EDIT: I guess it worked.

Answer (score 4):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MyTextBoxValidator" runat="server" 
   ControlToValidate="MyTextBox"
   ErrorMessage="Minimum length is 6"
   ValidationExpression=".{6}.*" />
```